# MarkLogic query taking too long

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am running a query in for loop which does update on a document. I have set the time-limit 36000.
However the query is running for more than 50 hours. I have used 20 threads and all those threads are taken by above query (since it is for loop).
Even after killing each query form admin and even after restarting the ML server, the next 20 query comes into queue and again those query running and occupying all threads.

```
let $_ := xdmp:set-request-time-limit(36000)
for $each in local:some-update-function()
let $document:= xdmp:invoke-function(function() {
local:another-update-function()
}, $constants:UPDATE_AUTO_COMMIT)
return $document
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code for `local:some-update-function()`  and `local:another-update-function()`.  Otherwise, it is hard to help diagnose. You have described the symptoms, but have not shown the code responsible for the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you have restarted the node that has the task server to clear the queue? And you can follow the URL https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/115/0/cancelling-an-active-task-in-the-task-server to cancel the tasks.

Comment: Also missing is *how* you are invoking these functions.  It makes no sense the code shown would use more then 1 thread, loops dont create threads.   Completely guessing given the symptoms and not enough info,  you are calling xdmp:spawnXXX somewhere or you keep invoking the function externally before its done.   Also from the names, it is likely you have created an effective deadlock by invoking a sub-function with an update lock still present.